# Number of ways for two people to select k items each such that every item occurs even number of times

Tags: combinatorics

Select $a_1,\dots,a_n, b_1,\dots, b_n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$ (non-negative integers) such that $|a| = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = k$ and $|b| = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i = k$, and further $a_i + b_i$ is even for each $i$.
How many ways are there?

Comment: How far did you get with it?  Is $n$ fixed as well as $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** So you want $a_i$ to be even iff $b_i$ is even. So select the indices where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are odd. If you select say $\ell$ of them, then you will have $2x+\ell=k,$ where $x$ now you want to partition it however you like, no? So you will need $\ell$ to have the same parity as $k.$ Add over all possibilities and use Stars and Bars when you have fixed the indices.

I get something like:

> $$\sum _{\ell \equiv k \pmod 2}\binom{n}{\ell}\binom{\frac{k-\ell}{2}+n-1}{n-1}^2$$